# How to loop through array and output in multiple columns?

Tags: coldfusion

I need help looping through my data and outputting it into multiple columns. Currently, it displays vertically right under the next set of data in the array. Please help.

```
      <cfloop array="#UserAddresses#" index="UA">

                <tr>
                    <td>City: </td>
                    <td><cfif NOT Len(#UA.city.xmlText#)>N/A<cfelse><cfoutput>#UA.city.xmlText#</cfoutput></cfif></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>State: </td>
                    <td><cfif NOT Len(#UA.state.xmlText#)>N/A<cfelse><cfoutput>#UA.state.xmlText#</cfoutput></cfif></td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td>Zip Code: </td>
                    <td><cfif NOT Len(#UA.zipcode.xmlText#)>N/A<cfelse><cfoutput>#UA.zipcode.xmlText#</cfoutput></cfif></td>
                </tr>                               
            </cfloop>
    </cfif>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the City, State and Zip Code to be headers? Then this would work

```cf
<cfoutput>
    <tr>
        <td>City: </td>
        <td>State: </td>
        <td>Zip Code: </td>
    </tr>
    <cfloop array="#UserAddresses#" index="UA">
        <tr>
            <td><cfif NOT Len(UA.city.xmlText)>N/A<cfelse>#UA.city.xmlText#</cfif></td>
            <td><cfif NOT Len(UA.state.xmlText)>N/A<cfelse>#UA.state.xmlText#<</cfif></td>
            <td><cfif NOT Len(UA.zipcode.xmlText)>N/A<cfelse>#UA.zipcode.xmlText#</cfif></td>
        </tr>                               
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

It works because `<tr></tr>` defines a table row and `<td></td>` defines a cell in that row. In your case, you were doing multiple rows without cells, thus you were getting your content in a column, instead of a row. A side note is that `<cfoutput></cfoutput>` should be used only once per page and not around every variable.